# Active Directory Password connection using JDBC(Java)

Tags: java, jdbc, active-directory, azure-active-directory, adal

I am trying to connect to SQL server using Active Directory Password authentication mode. But on executing the code I get the Following error:

```
    [pool-2-thread-1] INFO com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationAuthority 
  - [Correlation ID: 2febb587-963f-462a-9937-98b05d3a3fc8] Instance 
    discovery was successful
    [pool-2-thread-1] ERROR com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationContext - 
    [Correlation ID: 2febb587-963f-462a-9937-98b05d3a3fc8] Execution of 
    class com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AcquireTokenCallable failed.
    java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Collections$SingletonList cannot 
    be cast to java.lang.String
    at com.nimbusds.oauth2.sdk.util.URLUtils.serializeParameters(URLUtils.java:88)
    at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AdalTokenRequest.toOAuthRequest(AdalTokenRequest.java:160)
    at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AdalTokenRequest.executeOAuthRequestAndProcessResponse(AdalTokenRequest.java:86)
    at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationContext.acquireTokenCommon(AuthenticationContext.java:930)
at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AcquireTokenCallable.execute(AcquireTokenCallable.java:70)
at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AcquireTokenCallable.execute(AcquireTokenCallable.java:38)
at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AdalCallable.call(AdalCallable.java:47)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Exception in thread "main" com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Failed to authenticate the user e9002802@ltfinc.net in Active Directory (Authentication=ActiveDirectoryPassword).
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerADAL4JUtils.getSqlFedAuthToken(SQLServerADAL4JUtils.java:57)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.getFedAuthToken(SQLServerConnection.java:3853)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.onFedAuthInfo(SQLServerConnection.java:3829)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.processFedAuthInfo(SQLServerConnection.java:3797)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSTokenHandler.onFedAuthInfo(tdsparser.java:261)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSParser.parse(tdsparser.java:103)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.sendLogon(SQLServerConnection.java:4545)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.logon(SQLServerConnection.java:3406)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.access$100(SQLServerConnection.java:85)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection$LogonCommand.doExecute(SQLServerConnection.java:3370)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7347)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:2713)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:2261)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:1921)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectInternal(SQLServerConnection.java:1762)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:1077)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource.getConnectionInternal(SQLServerDataSource.java:1025)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource.getConnection(SQLServerDataSource.java:69)
at main.AADUserPassword.main(AADUserPassword.java:22)
  Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: 
  com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationException: 
  java.util.Collections$SingletonList cannot be cast to java.lang.String
  at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerADAL4JUtils.getSqlFedAuthToken(SQLServerADAL4JUtils.java:55) 
 ... 18 more  Caused by: com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationException: java.util.Collections$SingletonList cannot be cast to java.lang.String
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerADAL4JUtils.getSqlFedAuthToken(SQLServerADAL4JUtils.java:50)
... 18 more
```

I am not able to figure out, what exactly that exception(cannot cast to java.lang.string) means; also I have given correct username and password. I checked it using sql server management studio and it got connected. 
Please help. I am in a fix. Any help would be appreciated greatly.

Comment: You need to paste your code here.

Comment: Please include code that demonstrates where the issue is caused. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for more details.

Comment: Have you referred to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/connecting-using-azure-active-directory-authentication?view=sql-server-2017#connecting-using-activedirectorypassword-authentication-mode

Comment: Thanks for your response guys....that issue is fixe. It was some JAR Problem. Now it gets connected to Azure directory Password Authentication mode using JDBC.

Comment: Hi @Rik,  I helped you post this as the answer, you think about to  accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According comment, the error is solved by himself:

It was some JAR Problem. Now it gets connected to Azure directory Password Authentication mode using JDBC.

I posted this as answer and this can be beneficial to other community members.

Comment: If anyone wants to know about jars to download for azure directory Password, comment below. Will give you the link.

Comment: I would appreciate your input. Using ``mssql-jdbc`` version ``7.4.1.jre8`` and ``adal4j`` version ``1.6.6``

Comment: Can you share the list of jars required?

Comment: Please share the answer and not be so vague. JAR problem doesn't explain much.